# Bug in ASP.NET MVC - Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

@Html.Label acts weirdly. In example below first label is ignored, second label is rendered, and third label renders only "aaaaaaaaa"

```
@Html.Label("1234567890 absdfghjkl .")
@Html.Label("5555555555 ffffffffffff")
@Html.Label("3333333333. aaaaaaaaaaa")
```

It appears anything before period is ignored.
Is there any explanation for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's just [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.label): you're calling `Label(string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)` only with an expression.

Ultimately [`DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateLabel(... string expression, string labelText, ...)`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9a3aacb56af7221bfb29d851ee6b7c883650ddf6/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L410) is called,

You only pass the `expression`, which is used to determine the `for` attribute of the rendered `<label for="...">labelText</label>`. This allows you to [pass an expression that looks into your model](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/NameAndIdProvider.cs#L147) in order to tie a label to a control belonging to a model property, for example:

```
@Html.Label("Foo.Bar", "Toggle Foo's Bar")
```

If you don't pass a label text, the entire expression is used as label text, unless it contains a dot: then everything after the dot.

So pass an empty expression as first argument, then the text:

```
@Html.Label("", "My.Cool.Label")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the overload you're using `@Html.Label(string expression)`, try the overload `@Html.Label(string expression, string labelText)` `@Html.Label("", "3333333333. aaaaaaaaaaa")`